# How to automount NAS drive on WiFi

Tags: kubuntu, kde, systemd, automount, nas

I have Kubuntu 20.04 which I have connected to my (wpa2 encrypted) wifi. I have the password remembered in the system, so whenever I login to KDE the computer connects to my wifi.
I also have NAS on the same wifi and I would like to automout it. But this is only possible when I'm connected to wifi, which I guess happens after I log in to the KDE (because otherwise how it would know the password). 
Is there a way how to mount something automatically when I'm connected to wifi?
I tried to put the mounts to `/etc/fstab` and it aoutomounts if I have ethernet connection. On wifi thery are not mounted unless i do `sudo mount -a` 'manually'. 
I'm also not sure how to unmount correctly during shutdown. Just shutting down computer (via the KDE menu of course) sometimes stucks on the `umount`. I guess the wifi is already disconnected at that point so it can not correctly unmount and it just timeouts after like a minute, which blocks the shut down process.

Thanks

Comment: Posting as a comment since I've never used Kubuntu or 20.04, but in my 18.04 Ubuntu you can put scripts in  /etc/network/if-up.d and they get run when you connect to the network. So you could  put your mount command there if Kubuntu 20.04 works the same way.

Comment: Place two [Network Manager dispatcher scripts](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html): One to mount, one to unmount.

Comment: unfortunatelly the script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` is called when the interface is up but not connected to wifi, so it can not mount

Comment: The network manager dispatcher scripts mentioned by user535733 is what seems to be working in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually systemd takes the job of mounting and unmounting. I've done the following on two of my devices to connect to my NAS on demand:
Open fstab and enter the mount:

The scheme is [target] [mountpoint] [options]

```
//server/path /path/to/local/mount cifs username=XXX,password=YYY,noauto,_netdev,users  0 0
```

The mount will take place when you try to connect to your mountpoint, either by script or via files/nautilus. "noauto" is the flag that prevents your system to try to connect immediately.